# Mongoose connection repeatedly opens and close when connecting over local network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB instance running on my raspberry pi, and when I connect from my laptop using node and mongoose, the pi logs repeated connection/disconnection events to mongoDB.

The mongoose node connection is minimal:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.connect("mongodb://192.168.1.167:27017");
```

And this is the log from the pi:

```
Mon Jul 18 00:57:38.342 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Mon Jul 18 00:57:55.460 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.1.160:61752 #1 (1 connection now open)
Mon Jul 18 00:57:55.477 [conn1] end connection 192.168.1.160:61752 (0 connections now open)
Mon Jul 18 00:57:55.990 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.1.160:61755 #2 (1 connection now open)
Mon Jul 18 00:57:55.997 [conn2] end connection 192.168.1.160:61755 (0 connections now open)
Mon Jul 18 00:57:56.517 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.1.160:61757 #3 (1 connection now open)
...
```

Not sure why this is...

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope! Not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can happen if you don't use the right Mongoose version. If you are using the latest mongoose version with an older Mongo server, then this problem happens.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

See the chart in the link above and make sure you're running a compatible version of Mongoose for your MongoDB server. If not, simply update your package.json to install the right version.